# AngularJS Two lists: One list has all survey questions, and the other list has all the survey responses.

Tags: angularjs

I am a beginner at web development and using AngularJS so I am begging for any feedback.

I have a list of survey questions and I have a pop up modal where the user can give their response.  Over 500 survey questions are pulled from one table and put into an array to display in the view. When the user responds to each question, those responses are put into a separate table.  I have over 200 people taking this survey and no one can see the other people's responses.  My question is, how can I mark/hide the questions that they have already answered?  My beginner's go to solution was to do a for loop and iterate over the first list with the questions and then another for loop to iterate over the responses. If there the question Id was found in the second table, put into a new array where it will indicate that the question was answered.  But because there are so many responses and questions, the system crashed.  If anyone can help me figure out a solution for this, please let me know.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you can use a ng-if condition in your questions to figure out if the question was answered. The ng-if should have a condition where it can figure out if the question was answered

Comment: That worked! Thank you so much! The only problem I have now is pushing the grade from the pop up modal to my page without having to refresh to see the changes.

Comment: I am not sure when you say pushing the grade from the pop up modal. Please explain it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use ng-repeat to display questions and in that use ng-if with condition, for example:

```
 <div ng-repeat="q in question" ng-if="!q.answer">
  //all the stuff to display question
 </div>
```

Comment: That definitely made it work.  Thank you for your quick reply!